# Delphi (XE7) add Generic class to generic TDictionary

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

In the following code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyClass<T: TForm> = class
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  List: TDictionary<integer, TMyClass<TForm>>;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


{ TMyClass<T> }

constructor TMyClass<T>.Create;
begin
  List.Add(1, self);
end;

end.
```

I get error:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(35): E2010 Incompatible types:
>   'Unit1.TMyClass' and
>   'Unit1.TMyClass.T>'

in line where I am trying to add Self to the TDictionary. How can I add generic class to the TDictionary, where second parameter takes generic object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your constraint is ensuring that `T` can only be of `TForm` the compiler does not support what is called covariance.

What you can do is hardcast `Self` to `TMyClass<TForm>` to add it.

Comment: Thank you. Funny: the variable "List" must be inside interface, not implementation.